# how to change file path of vsdbcmd.exe of visual studio for database deployment

Tags: database, deployment

I try to deploy a visual studio database project, but error below:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Deploy\vsdbcmd.exe"
>   /ManifestFile:"D:\MyAppDB\sql\debug\MyApp.DB.deploymanifest"
>   /a:Deploy /dsp:sql
>   /script:"D:\MyAppDB\sql\debug\MyApp.DB.sql" /cs:"Data
>   Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated
>   Security=True;Pooling=False"
>   /p:GenerateDropsIfNotInProject=True
>   /p:BlockIncrementalDeploymentIfDataLoss=False
>   /p:TargetDatabase=MyAppBranchNational
>   /p:SqlCommandVariablesFile="D:\MyAppDB\Properties\Database.sqlcmdvars"
>   /p:IgnorePermissions=True
>   /p:GenerateDeployStateChecks=False
>   /dd:+   The system cannot find the
>   path specified.

The file vsdbcmd.exe is in 
F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Deploy

not in
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Deploy"

How to change the file path, so the database project will use the correct file.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Temporary solution:

I copied the folder below:

F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Deploy  (9MB)

to

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Deploy

and it works.

Meanwhile, welcome to any better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

"%vs100comntools%....\vstsdb\deploy\vsdbcmd.exe"

if you installed vs2008, then use "%vs90comntools%"

to find out all environment variables, open a command prompt and type "set"; or "set v" to show all variables started with "v".